# Preventing compilers from defining copy constructors and operator = overload for C++ Classes

Tags: c++, class

Is there a way by which we can prevent compilers from defining copy constructors, operator = overload for C++ classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare these functions as private which prevents people from using them when working with your class and at the same time prevents the compiler from generating them.

Comment: Note that this will not prevent the *declaration* of such functions, as you've just declared them yourself, and the compiler may still consider them when appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Derive from boost::noncopyable.

(There're also NIH ways to do that, by declaring the private never-defined methods for operator= and copy constructor, but, please love boost).

Answer (score 3):

Declare those functions yourself and make them private. Also you can didn't write definitions of that functions, so everyone who try to use those functions - will get an linker error.

Answer (score 3):

In C++0x, you'll be able to write

```
class NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable & operator=(NonCopyable const&) = delete;
  NonCopyable(NonCopyable const&) = delete;
};
```

Note that the compiler will not generate converting `NonCopyable::operator=(Other const&)` overloads in any case.

Comment: You get much nicer error messages this way, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Defining? Well, yes. They are always *declared* (explicitly by you or implicitly by the compiler), but they are only *defined* by the compiler when/if you actually use them. Don't use them - and the compiler will not define them.

Of course, if by "prevent compilers from defining ...", you mean "prevent compilers from *successfully* defining...", i.e. if you want to make the implicit definition attempt fail at compile time, then you can achieve that by adding non-copy constructible and/or non-assignable subobject to your class (like a base or member with private copy-constructor and private assignment operator, for example).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Firstly, what's "not necessarily"? `const` member is a non-assignable subobject. Secondly, what you are saying is not entirely correct. Copy-assignment is *always declared*. It is the *definition* attempt that will fail in case of a `const` member, just like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from a type that declares those functions in the private scope, such as boost::noncopyable.

Or...have a reference member variable :P

Answer (score 0):

FWIW if you ever get around to using Qt then you can use the `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();

private:
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(Foo)
};
```