# How to make a C++ class produce non cloneable objects

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, copy-constructor

How can I make a **Class** non-cloneable like we can do in Java while creating singleton.

Is there any condition we can put on copy constructor so that an exception can be thrown if user tries to make a copy of an object?

I am a novice in C++ so kindly add any info to this or redirect if an answer is already available for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing compilers from defining copy constructors and operator = overload for C++ Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082900/preventing-compilers-from-defining-copy-constructors-and-operator-overload-for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare copy constructor and copy assign operator private

in **C++03**

```
class NonCopyable
{
public:
   NonCopyable() { }

private:
   NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&);
   NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&);

};
```

Also you can make a class derive from NonCopyable, AnotherType is un-copyable

```
class AnotherNonCopyable : private NonCopyable
{
   public:
     AnotherNonCopyable () {}
}
```

With **C++11**:

```
class NonCopyableType
{
public:
  NonCopyableType(const NonCopyableType&) = delete;
  NonCopyableType& operator=(const NonCopyableType&) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(const& Foo) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

If you don't have C++11 support, make them private, and don't implement them:

```
struct Foo
{
 private:
  Foo(const& Foo);
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
};
```

**Note** In C++, `class` and `struct` are essentially the same.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the copy-semantics as `delete`:

```
//C++11 only

MyClass(MyClass const &) = delete;            
MyClass& operator=(MyClass const &) = delete;
```

That makes the class non-copyable!

```
//pre-C++11 code

private:
  MyClass(MyClass const &);             //declare only, don't define it      
  MyClass& operator=(MyClass const &);  //declare only, don't define it
```

This should also work!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any condition we can put on copy constructor so that an
>   exception can be thrown if user tries to make a copy of an object.

if you make the copy constructor private, The code will not compile when the programmer tries to make another copy. This is probably better than detecting the error with an exception at runtime.

```
class foo {
    private:
         operator = ( const foo& f);
};
```